# How do you detach an onSnapshot listener from Firebase Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've browsed for the last few hours but have been entirely unable to successfully detach an onSnapshot listener.
Currently my HTML is:

```
  <nav>
    <butt onclick="navButt(`Chat`)" class="navItem">Chat</butt>
    <butt onclick="navButt(`Staff`)" class="navItem">Staff</butt>
    <butt onclick="navButt(`Logout`)" class="navItem">Signout</butt>
  </nav>

  <module id="Chat" class="mod">
    <h3>Chat</h3>
  </module>

  <module id="Staff" class="mod active">
    <h3>Users</h3>
    <ul id="usersList">
      <li><span>User 1 Name</span><span>User 1 email</span></li> //Planned output of data, using console logging for testing, though.
    </ul>
  </module>
```

And my Javascript is:

```
function staff(){
FS.collection('users').where('company','==',`${userToken.claims.company}`).onSnapshot(snap=>{
        let userList = []
        snap.forEach(function(doc){
            userList.push(doc.data().email);
        })
        console.log('Users: ' + userList)
    })
}

function navButt (butt) {
let unsubscribe = FS.collection('users').where('company','==',`${userToken.claims.company}`).onSnapshot(function(){}) //placed inside so the auth token can be populated first
//I've also tried FS.collection('users').onSnapshot(function(){}) //but this results in a permission error since users can only read other user docs of the same company
    switch (butt) {
        case 'Logout':
            FA.signOut();
            break;
        case 'Chat':
            changeMod(butt);
            unsubscribe(); //This is where I've tried all the things
            break;
        case 'Staff':
            changeMod(butt)
            staff();
            break;
        default:
            console.log('No tied function')
            break;
    }
}

//Change Module
function changeMod (target) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.mod').forEach((modules)=>{modules.classList.remove('active')})
    document.querySelector(`#${target}`).classList.add('active')}
```

If some kind soul could look at my onSnapshot function above and show me what the detaching code should look like, that would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to show the complete code sample that doesn't work the way you expect.  The unsubscribe function definitely works - you're probably just doing something wrong that we can't see here.  I suggest also reading about best practices for creating a minimal, complete code sample: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I've updated my question,  let me know if there's still  more I need to add.

Comment: It's still not really a complete code sample.  You have some snippets, but we can't see how they fit together as a whole.  You should show how you obtain the unsubscribe function, then how you call it, all from the context of a single working program.  Showing the Firebase docs code sample doesn't really help with that - show what *you* did instead.

Comment: Updated again, thank you for being patient with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out and understand capturing and calling the unsubscribe. Only started learning Javascript a month ago, so for those in the same shoes, here's my fix:

```
        case 'Chat':
        changeMod(butt);
        try {unsubscribe()} catch {} //Since it won't exist on the first click, wrap in a try{}
        var unsubscribe = FS.collection('users').where('company','==',`${userToken.claims.company}`).onSnapshot(snap=>{ //Use a var so it can be initialized and declared repeatedly, but also the first time. Alternatively, use a let globally set to '' (nothing) and just "unsubscribe = "
            let userList = []
            snap.forEach(function(doc){
                userList.push(doc.data().email);
            })
            console.log('Users: ' + userList)
        }) //What got me was that capturing the onSnapshot in a variable IS creating the snapshot listener, it's a two in one action. Mind blown.
        break;

    case 'Staff':
        changeMod(butt)
        try {unsubscribe()} catch {} //Once it's been captured it will be "true" because it exists, and can be called to unsubscribe the last one before being set to the new one.
        var unsubscribe = FS.collection('users').where('company','==',`${userToken.claims.company}`).onSnapshot(snap=>{
            let userList = []
            snap.forEach(function(doc){
                userList.push(doc.data().email);
            })
            console.log('Users: ' + userList)
        })
        break;
```

When reading anything on it I just always interpreted the capturing of unsubscribe to be it's own, independent action.